# How do I diagnose if there is a leak causing the hot water to continuously run?

Tags: wiring, plumbing, water-heater, leaks

---

Just installed a new water heater, filled it, turned on hot water faucets in the house til water was flowing then turned them off. Connected the wiring and waited for water to get hot. After about an hour still no hot water and it sounds like water running out of hot water pipe but there are no faucets open

Comment: Should be a valve right at the tank's outlet, turn that off.  An hour is probably too soon to even warm a tank full of cold water.

Comment: I can turn mine on for 15 minutes and have hot water in the top of it. Don't need it hot all the way to the bottom to have hot water available. If it sounds like running water, shut some valves and go looking for a leak or open faucet you forgot.

Answer (score 2):

Slowly turn off the valve on the cold side and listen for water flow.   It's unlikely that replacing the WH would create a substantial leak.  If you are on metered municipal water, check to see if the dial/meter is showing water flow.  Be sure everything in the house is turned off first.   I have to disagree with crip, you should be seeing hot water within 30 minutes.

If you detect flow, all you can do is try and trace it down to where it's going. Sorry, wish I could give better advice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of hooking up wiring, I assume this is an electric heater.  You can do a few checks to see if it's heating the water, and if so, if water is running somewhere.

To check to see if it's actually heating the water, you can look at your electric meter with the water heater turned off, then turn it on and confirm that the meter is spinning a lot faster, as an electric hot water heater will draw a lot of power while heating.  (I assume you turned off the circuit breaker to your water heater before disconnecting/reconnecting, then turned the breaker back on).  Also, if the water heater is heating the water, at least the output pipe should be warm/hot, even with no water running, just through the heat transfer of the hot water through the copper of the outlet pipe.

To see if any water is running, you can either look for a spinning water meter or turn off the inlet valve (as others have recommended), or don't run any water for about 30 minutes, then put your hand on the inlet and outlets to the water heater a couple feet away from the heater itself.  If there's water running, you'll feel the pipe temperature of the inlet side colder than room temp (assuming your water supply is colder than ambient), and if the water heater is heating the water, the outlet a couple feet away will be warm to the touch, compared to ambient.